# How to install a plugin in Logseq?

Tags: plugins

I want to install the plugin [logseq-plugin-tabs](https://github.com/haydenull/logseq-plugin-markdown-table). How do I do this?

Comment: Does [Logseq Plugin Setup Guide.md · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/xyhp915/bb9f67f5b430ac0da2629d586a3e4d69) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Developer Mode has to be activated for using Plugins.

1. Click the **3 dots** and choose **Settings** [image: Click the 3 dots and choose Settings]
2. Choose **Advanced** and enable **Developer Mode** [image: Choose Advanced and enable Developer Mode]
3. Find the **Plugins**[image: Find the Plugins]